# Can't unpublish joomla 2.5 module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I have joomla 2.5.6 package installed on my website. The problem is, in extension manager I can't unpublish any module, nor works the other way. What's that might be? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

To unpublish a module, you need to go the the Module Manager, not Extension Manager. Once there either switch between green and red buttons in the "status" column or click on the module and go to the "status" select box.

The extension manager is to install/uninstall, update and discover.